# Is there a way to create a task/workflow in powercenter that can load macros from excel?

Tags: excel, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm looking to use informatica powercenter in order to automate some processes which currently involve macros/modules from excel. I only have experience with using powercenter in order to import tables and perform various transformations on them to finally create a workflow which automates processes that I would have done through SQL server.

I've looked on Stack Overflow and the rest of the web to find a way to import excel macros but have not found any specific way or the answers would be relatively vague. I'm running Informatica Powercenter 10.1 and excel 2016.

The expected result I'd look for is to be able to set a workflow which has multiple macros loaded in procession (each assigned to their own task in the workflow) through just one workflow which eliminates the need to run each of them individually.

Comment: You could look into using a vbscript to run your excel macros, and presumably you could run that vbscript from Informatica (at a guess, not an Informatica user...)

Comment: Informatica is not a tool for executing Excel macros - it's a tool that could replace them. You could read the data and transform them the same way the macros do it and then store the results.